# I am trying to bind the same function to two images. When I click on an Img, I want that image to be resized only, not all images

Tags: javascript

As you see  I am trying to change the style of an image when I click on the image. However, when I run the function,

it changes the style of one image. I want to reuse the function to toggle the style of two images differently. For example, if I click on image1, I want image1 to become larger.

```js
        let x = document.getElementById("img1");
        let myImage2 = document.getElementById("img2");
        function change(x,y) {
            x.classList.toggle("fullsize");
            y.classList.toggle("fullsize");
        }
        x.addEventListener("click", change());
```

```css
        .img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .fullsize {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            background-size: contain;
            z-index: 999;
            cursor: zoom-out;
            display: block;
            width: 400px;
            max-width: 400px;
            height: 550px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Click to Open Zoom the image</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/287/1000/1000" class="img" id="img1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/1000/1000" class="img" id="img2">
</body>
```

let x = document.getElementById("img1");                  let myImage2 = document.getElementById("img2");                   function change(x,y) {                   x.classList.toggle("fullsize");                   y.classList.toggle("fullsize");                     }                   x.addEventListener("click", change());

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function change(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("fullsize");
}
document.querySelectorAll('.img').forEach((imgElm) => {
  imgElm.addEventListener('click', change);
});
```

```css
.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.fullsize {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: zoom-out;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Click to Open Zoom the image</h1>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/287/1000/1000" class="img" id="img1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/1000/1000" class="img" id="img2">
</body>
```

What this does is to get all elements that have class `img` (`document.querySelectorAll('.img')`), loop through all those elements (`.forEach(..)`) and add a click event listener using `change` as the callback.

The `change` function uses the event (the `event` variable) to get the element that was clicked (`event.target`) and toggle the `fullsize` class.